# When, if ever, does refining a question need to be a new question?

Tags: discussion

I recently [asked a question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42316/color-label-and-rating-recomendations) and when the answers came in I realized that my question was not asking what my brain was asking. I think now, instead of "Color label and rating recommendations," the question should be along the lines of "managing progress through the workflow" or something. My instinct is to edit the question to reflect what I had intended to ask, but it seems to me that the question may differ enough that the answers already submitted would be almost wildly out of place in the context of the new question. Any thoughts on how I should handle this?

Comment: Philip provided a great answer, but I would also look at some of the existing workflow questions to see if they answer your question.  I took the approach answering your question that I did because the question about workflows in Lightroom has been answered before on the site.

Answer (score 5):

My view would be that if your edit would make it essentially a different question, then it's better asked as a new question - otherwise you run the risk of having "irrelevant" answers with upvotes etc.

Comment: Philip has it nailed, tenmiles. Sounds like your question would become fundamentally different enough to warrant a new question, rather than an edit of the same question.